# Why don't my bathroom outlets work after an appliance power surge?

Tags: bathroom

My wife plugged a heater in the bathroom it zapped the lights and receptacles in the bathroom. Checked the breaker it was not tripped. Changed the outlets in the bathroom still no power. All outlets show hot when I put tester to it  but no power to the outlets . I have two outlets and a light switch that is not working one outlet in my bedroom and the outlet in the bathroom and a light switch. All are on one wall..

Comment: There is no power but you put a tester to it it shows hot.

Comment: Basic voltage testers often do in house wiring. I suggest a proper voltmeter.

Comment: Have you looked for a GFCI breaker that protects the circuit? Could be elsewhere in the house.

Comment: I have no GFCI in my bathroom

Comment: All outlets work in the hallway and in my bedroom but one and it's on the same circuit as the bathroom.

Comment: The problem here is that we don't know where you are, how old your home is, what kind of wiring and service panel you have, etc., etc. Help us help you!

Comment: What does "All outlets show hot when I put tester to it but no power to the outlets" mean?

Comment: Were the backstabs used on the outlet or switches?

Comment: All the dead outlets are on the same circuit, right?

Answer (score 3):

Having a circuit failure when using a portable heater is probably the number one cause of receptacles not working.

In the U.S. The most common cause is use of back stabs (push in wire connectors). After that loose wirenuts then a loose or broken wire or wire in the service panel.
Your receptacles show hot but what about the return or neutral? If this connection is damaged the circuit won’t work but will show hot with a non contact tester.

If you work towards the service panel on this circuit the last working receptacle or switch or the first non working one will be where the failure is. Use a light or hair dryer to see which outlet it is. Turn off the power and look in this case for a loose, burned off or broken white wire, if things look good with back stabs and things start working when you turn the power back on the circuit will probably fail again when under heavy load so if you find backstabs it is best to move those connections to the screw terminals or if no terminals buy a receptacle that has them, 99c specials work 3-5$ specification grade are worth the extra and will last longer and hold the plug better.